# Checking one checkbox to uncheck another in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I have five checkboxes, and only one of them can be checked at a time.   Is there a way to do this in the form's XAML?

I can do this in the set method of the corresponding model property for each checkbox (If true, set all others to false.)

Comment: Did you try Binding a Converter to the IsChecked property of the checkbockes?

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons instead. This is exactly what they are for.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the only thing I can really think of here is that if having zero options selected was valid, it'll require a little extra work to do that with `RadioButton`s (I believe). But I agree... Based on the question, OP should probably be using `RadioButton`s instead.